# Gaufre et gauffre

Tags: orthographe

Jusqu'à aujourd'hui, j'étais dans la certitude totale que « gaufre » s’épelait « gauffre ». Or lorsque j'ai appris que ce n'était pas le cas, j'ai voulu savoir si j'étais la seule à penser cela. Il semble que ce ne soit pas le cas. Cette tendance de recherche Google démontre que bien des gens l'épellent incorrectement.

(« Gaufre » en bleu et « Gauffre » en rouge)

[image]

**Pourquoi tant de personnes écrivent gaufre avec deux F? Y a-t-il une raison particulière?**

Comment: Un schéma qui nous apprend *également* que, contre toute attente, septembre 2011 a été le mois de la gauf(f)re.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Je pense qu'un facteur qui contribue est que la lettre `f` est souvent doublée lorsqu'elle est précédée d'une voyelle. Si je regarde dans la liste de mots de mon correcteur orthographique (donc avec toutes les formes verbales, et sans pondération par la fréquence ; j'omets les noms propres) :

- 2668 `[aeiou]ff` contre 3722 avec un seul `f` (autrement dit, 40% des F précédés d'une voyelle sont doublés)
- 126 `[aeiou]fr` contre 401 `[aeiou]ffr`

(`[aeiou]` signifie « une voyelle » — je néglige le Y — et `[^f]` signifie « tout sauf `f` »). Si on regarde spécifiquement les mots se terminant par `-fre`, il y en a que 4 : *balafre*, *fifre*, *gaufre* et *soufre* (l'élément chimique, lui aussi souvent mal orthographié). Certes, il n'y a que 5 mots (et leurs dérivés) en `-ffre`, mais ils sont plus courants : *chiffre*, *coffre*, *gouffre*, *offre*, *souffre* (de *souffrir*). En particulier, on a là 5 racines verbales en `-ffr-`, alors que *gaufrer* est la seule avec un seul `f`.

L'orthographe avec deux `f` est attestée chez quelques auteurs, au moins pour l'adjectif *gauffré* : le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gaufr%C3%A9) cite Eugène Viollet-le-Duc, Elsa Triolet et Jacqueline Viaux. Plus anciennement, le [*Ménagier de Paris*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nagier_de_Paris) de la fin du XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle écrit *gauffre* (signalé sur [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaufre_%28cuisine%29)). On retrouve aussi l'orthographe *gauffre* comme variante du mot anglais *[goffer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/goffer)* venu par le français. La première édition du *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française* écrit systématiquement *gauffre* ; la quatrième édition ne retient plus que *gaufre*.

Il semble donc que le doublement du `f` soit une ancienne orthographe, désuète depuis longtemps (quoique peut-être conservée régionalement), et qui a la vie dure à cause du caractère inhabituel du `f` non doublé.

Comment: *Balafre* est aussi une racine verbale (*balafrer*).

Answer (score 4):

Pour information:

- Une gaufre en anglais se dit: *a waffle* avec deux *f*
- Une gaufre en néerlandais s'écrit: *wafel* avec un seul *f*
- Une gaufre en allemand: *eine Waffel*, deux *f*.

En français l'orthographe la moins usitée, avec un seul *f*, est considérée comme correcte.

Il semblerait qu'il nous suffit juste de nous mettre d'accord :)